# Windows 10 - How to avoid the automatic switching to a another active windows?

Tags: python, windows-10

I have a Python program who automates the fill in of a a form on an internal website from our company(through Chrome).

The problem is: everytime that the windows of Chrome used by the Python programm will be updated or refreshed, it comes on first line and my mouse goes automatically on this windows. It doesn't matter what I m doing in parallel.

I just want this working background and not pop up in front every time the website will be refreshed by the automate program.

Which function should I desactivate in Windows 10 Enterprise ?

Thanks !

Comment: Could you include some detail  of how your script works? How did you write the interaction with chrome?

Comment: It has nothing with my programm to do. It's also the same case for example if I open manually many PDF documents in the Acrobat. If I switch to another stuff, every time the Acrobat will open a document, the windows will come on front line automatically. It's a windows problem I think

Comment: Sorry, you re maybe right. Ich habe this point: browser.switch_to_window(window_before) und Chromes steals always Focus at this point. So I need a function to tell Python to look for ID in the new windows but without stealing focus. :)